# How to get the length of video inside iframe via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to get two things from iframe, first is total length and second one is current time of video running inside iframe.
I can't use `<video>` tag in my case and my iframe `src` is a HTML link not mp4. Here is a demo link I'm using in iframe `src`

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/brainimac/tutorials/ipad/iPad+Three+Types/media/index_player.html`

```
$('#getTime').on('click', function() {
  var vid = document.getElementById("vid");  
  var currentTime = vid.length;
  $('#currentTime').html(currentTime);
 });

CurrentTime returns undefine
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Due to the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) you can't access the contents of an iframe, unless the src of the iframe is the same domain (and protocol+port) as the main frame. So assuming your website isn't running on https://s3.amazonaws.com/ you can't retrieve your data.

However, that video is accessible via the following mp4-url, so that might solve your problem. Note that embedding the video this way, might conflict with their copyright license!!!

https://s3.amazonaws.com/brainimac/tutorials/ipad/iPad+Three+Types/media/iPad%20Three%20Types.mp4

Comment: Problem is that when I used mp4 link it don't provide me QUIZ function at the last of every video, that's why I've to use html link